# Using Bio.SeqIO to write single-line FASTA

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

QIIME requests this ([here](http://qiime.org/documentation/file_formats.html)) regarding the fasta files it receives as input:

`The file is a FASTA file, with sequences in the single line format. That is, sequences are not broken up into multiple lines of a particular length, but instead the entire sequence occupies a single line.`

`Bio.SeqIO.write` of course follows the [format recommendations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format), and splits the sequence every 80 bps. 
I could write my own writer to write those "single-line" fastas - but my question is if there's a way that I missed to make `SeqIO` do that.

Comment: Bioinformatics questions may find a more specialized audience at https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: Lucky me you were here then. SO is where I'm used to go to... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BioPython's `SeqIO` module uses the `FastaIO` submodule to read and write in FASTA format.

The `FastaIO.FastaWriter` class can output a different number of characters per line but this part of the interface is not exposed via `SeqIO`. You would need to use `FastaIO` directly.

So instead of using:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
SeqIO.write(data, handle, format)
```

use:

```
from Bio.SeqIO import FastaIO
fasta_out = FastaIO.FastaWriter(handle, wrap=None)
fasta_out.write_file(data)
```

or

```
for record in data:
    fasta_out.write_record(record)
```

Comment: `write_file()` and `write_record()` are marked OBSOLETE in BioPython (now).

Answer (score 2):

@unode answered the question. I just want to add that `write_file()` and `write_record()` from `FastaIO` are marked OBSOLETE as of today. So an alternative solution is to use `as_fasta_2line()` function, which converts a fasta record into a plain two-line string.

```
from Bio.SeqIO import FastaIO
records_list = [FastaIO.as_fasta_2line(record) for record in records]
handle.writelines(records_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Though both @unode and @HongboZhu provided working answers to the question, they used `FastaIO`.
`SeqIO` (now at least, and in Python3) provides functionality to write in the format you desire:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
SeqIO.write(data, handle, 'fasta-2line')
```